# CSS file is not working in react component

Tags: css, reactjs, frontend, create-table, react-component

In my react component, I have imported CSS file from the CSS directory, but the CSS isn't being applied to the component.

This is my folder structure

[image]

This is my code on the homepage.jsx file

```
import React from 'react';
import './homepage-styles.scss';

class HomePage extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="homepage-container">
        <h1>Hello World</h1>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
export default HomePage;
```

And this is the CSS file

```
.homepage-container {
  background: red;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

When I put the same CSS in the index.css file which is automatically created by the create-react-app, then the styling is visible.
What is the problem here? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any problem in your code whatever you have posted.

for your reference

JSX

```
import React from "react";
import "./homepage-styles.scss";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="homepage-container">
      <h1>Hello World</h1>
    </div>
  );
}
```

sass

```
.homepage-container {
  background: red;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

Live [Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/example-ouob3)

> Make sure you have installed `node-sass` package.

Comment: Node-sass did the trick. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you have to import styles to specific files in this way:

```
import React from 'react';
import styles from './homepage-styles.scss';

class HomePage extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className={`${styles[homepage-container]}`}>
                <h1>Hello World</h1>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default HomePage;
```

Notice that the [] brackets are only for multi-word scss classes. If your class would be just named `homepage`, then the proper way would be `` className={`${styles.homepage}`} ``